# warning: passing argument 1 of 'enlistar' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

Tags: c, lista

Intento implementar un Hash en C. El programa compila, pero en el archivo myHash.h tira la siguiente advertencia:

> warning: passing argument 1 of 'enlistar' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

Archivo myHash.h

```
#ifndef MYHASH_H_INCLUDED
#define MYHASH_H_INCLUDED
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define HASHMAX 10

typedef struct nodoL {
    int info;
    struct nodoL * sig;
    struct nodoL * ant;
} * lista;

// DEFINICIÓN DE LAS FUNCIONES
//************* HASH **********

typedef lista Hash[HASHMAX];
int HashClave(int n);
void HashInsertar(Hash *h, int e);
void HashMostrar(Hash h);
void HashBuscar(Hash h, int n);

//********  LISTA   *******
void enlistar (lista *L, int n);
int mostrar(lista L);/* muestra por pantalla los valores de L, en forma recursiva */
void borrar(lista *L, int n);   

#endif // MYHASH_H_INCLUDED
```

Todo bien.

Archivo myHash.c

```
#include "myHash.h"

int HashClave (int n)
{
    return n%HASHMAX;
}

void HashInsertar (Hash *h, int e){
    enlistar ((h)[HashClave(e)],e);
}

void enlistar (lista *L, int n){ //<--note: expected 'struct nodoL **' but argument is of type 'struct nodoL *'
        lista aux = (lista)malloc(sizeof( struct nodoL ));
        if(*L==NULL){
           aux -> info = n;
           aux -> sig = *L;
           *L=aux;
      }
       else{
           if((*L)->info>n){// Para que quede ordenado
               aux -> info = n;
               aux -> sig = *L;
               *L=aux;
           }
           else{
               enlistar((*L)->sig,n); //<-- warning: passing argument 1 of 'enlistar' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
           }
      }
}

int mostrar (lista L)
{
    int i=0;
    if(L!=NULL)
    {
        i=1;
        printf("[%d]->",L->info);
        mostrar(L->sig);
    }
    return i;
}

void HashMostrar(Hash h){
    int i, n;
    for (n=0;n<HASHMAX;n++){
        printf("Hash [%d]: ",n);
        i=mostrar(h[n]);
        if(i==0)printf("Lista  vacia \n\n");
        else printf("# \n\n");
    }
}

void borrar(lista *L, int n)
{
    lista aux = *L; //puntero auxiliar al primer nodo
    lista ant = NULL;
    if(aux==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Lista vacia");
    }
    else
    {
        while (aux->info!=n&&aux->sig!=NULL)
        {
            ant=aux;
            aux=aux->sig;
        }
        if(aux->sig==NULL&&aux->info!=n)
            printf("Error, numero no se encuentra en la lista");
        else
        {
            ant->sig=aux->sig;
            free (aux);   //elimino el nodo de la memoria
        }
    }
}
```

Adicionalmente tira la siguiente nota:

> note: expected 'struct nodoL **' but argument is of type 'struct nodoL *' en la línea marcada.

¿Qué puede estar pasando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El aviso es claro: estás pasándole un **tipo de puntero** incorrecto a tu función `enlistar( )`.

```
void enlistar (lista *L, int n);
```

Esperas un doble puntero a una `struct nodeL`.

```
enlistar((*L)->sig,n);
```

Estás *desreferenciando* el puntero. Como apunta a una `nodoL`, coges su campo `struct nodoL * sig`.

**Pero** ... ese campo es un **puntero simple**, y no doble.

Aparte de eso, tu código hace cosas *raras*:

```
lista aux = malloc( sizeof( lista ) );
  if( L == NULL ) {
    aux -> info = n;
    aux -> sig = *L;
    *L = aux;
  }
  ...
```

Creas en memoria dinámica ... **un puntero** a una estructura, no la estructura en si. Y, basándote en ese puntero (que está sin inicializar, y puntará a cualquier parte), escribes valores ... el resultado de eso ha de ser bastante *curioso* :-)

No estoy seguro de lo que pretendes hacer al pasar un **doble puntero** como argumento. La solución es cambiar la llamada problemática:

```
enlistar( (*L).sig, n );
```

**No** desreferenciar el puntero, sino pasarlo *tal cual*.

#### EDITO

Al final, me has *obligado* a codificar un caso de prueba y todo ;-)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct nodoL {
  int info;
  struct nodoL * sig;
} *lista;

void enlistar( lista *L, int n ) {
  lista aux = (lista)malloc( sizeof( struct nodoL ) );

  aux->info = n;

  if( *L == NULL ) {
    aux->sig = NULL;
    *L = aux;
  } else {
    if( (*L)->info > n ) {
      aux->sig = *L;
      *L = aux;
    } else {
      enlistar( &(*L)->sig, n );
    }
  }
}

void mostrar( lista nodo ) {
  if( nodo ) {
    printf( "%p -> %d, %p\n", nodo, nodo->info, nodo->sig );
    mostrar( nodo->sig );
  }
}

int main( void ) {
  lista Lista = NULL;

  enlistar( &Lista, 4 );
  enlistar( &Lista, 2 );
  enlistar( &Lista, 5 );
  enlistar( &Lista, 1 );
  enlistar( &Lista, 3 );

  mostrar( Lista );

  return 0;
}
```

Salen 2 *warnings* en la llamada a `printf( )`, pero se pueden ignorar tranquilamente.

Comment: Hacer lo que recomiendas tira el siguiente `error error: request for member 'sig' in something not a structure or union`

Comment: @AlejandroCaro Editado. Ahora, con mas tiempo :-)

Comment: ¡Cómo vas a ignorar una advertencia!

Comment: @AlejandroCaro Porque la advertencia es que `printf( "%p" )` espera un `void *`, y yo le estoy pasando un `lista` (aka `struct nodoL *`). Es un puntero igual. Son cosas de la *puntillosidad* de algunos compiladores. Ni caso ;-)

Comment: Lo que hay que hacer es castear las asignaciones `nodo` y `nodo->sig` especificando que son de tipo void * (punteros vacíos pienso yo) y des referenciarlos. Quedaría así `(void*)&nodo` y `(void*)&nodo->sig`

Comment: Si tu lo dices :-)

Comment: Lo saqué de stackoverflow en inglés

Comment: @AlejandroCaro Se de sobra como se soluciona, gracias no obstante. La cuestion es que no importa, no le des mas vueltas :-) Ademas, está en una parte del código para verificar pruebas, no afecta a tu código.